# Amazon MWS inventory XML feed doesn't update quantity

Tags: amazon-mws

I'm trying to upload my inventory to Amazon via XML feed, but my quantity in seller central doesn't update.

My XML feed is below. Can anyone help find my mistake?

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?><AmazonEnvelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="amzn-envelope.xsd">
<Header>
<DocumentVersion>1.01</DocumentVersion>
<MerchantIdentifier>A3QPCC6I4V1QU3</MerchantIdentifier>
</Header>
<MessageType>Inventory</MessageType>
<Message>
<MessageID>1</MessageID>
<OperationType>Update</OperationType>
<Inventory>
<SKU>BHAL10105</SKU>
<Quantity>1</Quantity>
<Available>true</Available>
<FulfillmentLatency>7</FulfillmentLatency>
</Inventory>
</Message>
</AmazonEnvelope>
```

Comment: How are you submitting your feed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you submit your feed, you will receive a `FeedSubmissionId` identifying it. Then it will be processed in the background.

- When the processing has completed, you can use the **[GetFeedSubmissionResult](http://docs.developer.amazonservices.com/en_US/feeds/Feeds_GetFeedSubmissionResult.html)** operation to retrieve the result to see if it was successful, or why it was unsuccessful.
- You can also check the most recent feeds by logging in to Amazon Seller Central and opening [this page](https://sellercentral.amazon.com/gp/item-manager/ezdpc/uploadInventory.html/ref=pt_invfile_dnav_home_).
- You can also use the [Amazon MWS Scratchpad](https://mws.amazonservices.com/scratchpad/index.html) to submit the operation to check the result.

Answer (score 0):

thanks for your advices,i solved !!.
i must   upload to amazon a txt file whith the inventory calculated by software.
then i have created an inventory  txt file and with api mws i upload it to amazon with this feetype  _POST_FLAT_FILE_INVLOADER_DATA_